# Docker composer, constraint - did not find expected key

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We using docker CE(latest) and docker composer version 3.I have a .yml for for 3 services but I want to constraint grafana to the master of the swarm.
When adding the constraint I get

> yaml: line 32: did not find expected key
>   Tthe script is this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: "influxdb:latest"
    volumes:
      - /mount/set/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
    ports:
      - "5076:5076"
    networks:
      - production

  kapacitor:
    image: "kapacitor:latest"
    environment:
      KAPACITOR_HOSTNAME: kapacitor
      KAPACITOR_INFLUXDB_0_URLS_0: http://influxdb:5086
    volumes:
      - /mount/set/kapacitor:/var/lib/kapacitor
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - production

  grafana:
    image: "grafana/grafana:latest"
      ports:
        - "7000:7000"
      networks:
        - production
      deploy:
        placement:
          constraints: [node.role == manager]
      volumes:
        - /iSCSIDisk/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
        - /iSCSIDisk/grafana/lib:/var/lib/grafana
      environment:
        GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: secretsecret

      networks:
        production:
          external: true
```

I combed over the script several times and could not find any reason for the error, I may be overlooking something, I checked for non-spaces etc, and could not find anything, I checked other articles regarding the same error, and I don't seem to have any missing brackets or duplicates too. Your help will be much appreciated, thank you. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your indentation is broken in the grafana section. Everything after `image` is spaced in two extra spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess yml files are picky like that :)

Comment: Yup, someone took a page out of the python manual when making the yml syntax.

Comment: Wow - 1.5 hours looking at a similar issue in my .yaml fine - thank you for this. Grrrr :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is common error with docker-compose.yml file depend on extra spaces.
If you use vi or vim  you can remove all extra spaces with  `:%s/\s\+$//e` command.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are using dictionary type declarations for your environment variables.

In my case I had to change the format

```
environment:      
  DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: "${DATASTORE_ENDPOINT}:${DATASTORE_PORT}"
```

to

```
environment:
  - DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=${DATASTORE_ENDPOINT}:${DATASTORE_PORT}
```

The only thing that changed for me was upgrading my docker desktop installation

Answer (score 0):

You've got your answer already, but I just stumbled on another (in hindsight obvious) issue: double quotes in a value when it is quoted with double quotes.

E.g.:

```yaml
...
environment:
  PASSWORD: "a"123"
...
```

To fix, one should use single quotes:

```yaml
...
environment:
  PASSWORD: 'a"123'
...
```